# Timeout error when starting Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: python, virtual-machine

When i run virt-manager in terminal, there is timeout error. How do we fix this error?

Below is the call stack.

> Error starting Virtual Machine Manager: g-io-error-quark: Timeout was reached (24)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager", line 288, in  main()
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-manager", line 272, in main

```
engine = vmmEngine.get_instance()
```

> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/engine.py", line 54, in get_instance

```
cls._instance = vmmEngine()
```

> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/engine.py", line 68, in **init**
>       self._init_gtk_application()
>
> File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/engine.py", line 282, in _init_gtk_application

```
self._application.register(None)
```

> gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: Timeout was reached (24)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) virt-manager process needs to restarted. To find the virt-manager process, ps aux command has to be used. ps command is not showing the required process list.

> ps aux | grep virt

2) Terminate all the virt-manager process listed with kill command

3) Restart libvirtd service

> systemctl start libvirtd